# Toggling a conditionalPanel within rintrojs

Tags: shiny, shinyjs, intro.js, action-button

I would like an introduction using rintrojs that highlights a button that toggles between showing and not showing a conditionalpanel. If the conditional panel is not showing, when the intro gets to that step I would like it to be selected so that it is showing. This I have accomplished using `Shiny.setInputValue`.

The trouble is that the toggle action button no longer works after doing the introduction. The value of the action button will still increase but it will no longer toggle the conditionalPanel.

Here is an example that has two intro steps and changes the conditionalPanel in the 'onchange' option of the `introjs` function in the observeEvent.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(rintrojs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  introjsUI(), 
  sidebarPanel(
  introBox(
    actionButton(
      "toggle",
      "Toggle"
    ),
    data.step = 1,
    data.intro = "Step 1"
  ),
  conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.toggle % 2 == 1', 
                   style = "display: none;",
                   introBox(  
                     tags$h4("some text displayed when toggled"), 
                     data.step = 2, 
                     data.intro = "Step 2"
                   )
  ),
  br(),
  actionButton("help", "Take Tour")
))

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$toggle, {
    print(input$toggle)
  })

  
  observeEvent(input$help, {
    print("in input$help observe event")
    introjs(
      session,
      options = list(
        "nextLabel" = "Next",
        "prevLabel" = "Back",
        "skipLabel" = "Exit"
      ),
      
      events = list(
        onchange = I(
          'if (this._currentStep==1) {
                  Shiny.setInputValue("toggle", 1)
            }'
        )
        #, 
        # oncomplete = {print("yes")
        #   updateActionButton(session = session, 
        #                      inputId = "Toggle", 
        #                      label = "Boggle"
        #   )
        #   print("done")}
      )
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. I am open to other solutions that solve the toggle between conditional panel problem in other ways (not using Shiny.setInputValue inside the 'onchange' portion). In the commented code you can see I have tried to update the toggle action button in the 'oncomplete' portion but the introjs function doesn't seem to like that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Strange. You can trigger a click on the button instead:

```r
        onchange = I(
          'if (this._currentStep == 1 ) {
             $("#toggle").click();
           }'
        )
```